# AlarmManager Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I have a problem executing the following code:

```
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MedicineEntry.this, DisplaySchedule.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MedicineEntry.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 25);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MedicineEntry.this, "Alarm Will Start In A Second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
```

To elucidate my problem, the app should fire up according to the values set for HOUR_OF_DAY, MINUTE and SECOND - even if the device is in sleep mode. I've tried testing the code, but the app does not seem to work. I've tried replacing AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES with 5*1000 which worked fine. Please go easy with the terminologies. I've just started to program with Android this semester at college.

EDIT: This app I am creating is a 'reminder' app. The user is expected to enter the time which the app should execute.

Comment: Post your `DisplaySchedule` class

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways of interacting with the AlarmManager. Your post is somewhat vague about which will suit your needs.

Anyway, if you want an **"Do every 15 minutes"** type of alarm, use the ELAPSED mode:

```
long firstActivation = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(); // and not System.currentTimeMillis()
mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstActivation, INTERVAL_MILLISECS, intent);
```

But, if you're looking for an **"Do every day at 15:30"** semantics, use RTC mode, like this:

```
  long activationTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
  long TWENTY_FOUR_HRS = 24 * 60 * 60* 1000;
  mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, activationTime, TWENTY_FOUR_HRS, intent);
```

Two things to note at the above code:

**A.** I am using a waking up type of alarms. These are potentially expensive as they would wake up a sleeping device. Are you sure this is what you need (hint: most apps do not)?

**B.** I am using [setInexactRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) instead of [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) so to allow the alarm manager to batch together several alarms thus saving resources. If you do not have a good reason not to do so, stick to using setInexactRepeating()

Comment: Hi, this app I am creating is a 'reminder' app. The user is expected to enter the time which the app should execute. I used the INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES method just to test my code. I will likely use the INTERVAL_DAY method.